# Prevent unwanted characters in the file name field when loading with fileLoad.click( )

Tags: javascript, file

In my JavaScript project, reading in data using a single button works perfectly.

However, I also have to read in data when I click on an object with the mouse in an area "ContainerB" while holding down a key such as <kbd>s</kbd> for "shape". This works fine in itself, the problem is that when the "Upload file" window opens, there are already quite a number of "s" letters in the active "File name" input field. If you don't get your finger off the <kbd>s</kbd> very quickly, there are a lot of characters.

This is very unpleasant. How can you prevent this?
It should be empty or contain a default value like "shape.txt"?

My structure:

```html
    <input type="file" id="shapeFileLoad" style="display: none;">
```

```js
    function onWindowKeyDown( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === 83 )  key = 'shape';     //  load a shape file 
    }
    function onWindowKeyUp( event ) {
        key = ''; // reset keyCode  
    }   
    function onContainerBpointerDown( event ) {
      if ( key === 'shape' ) {
        shapeFileLoad.click( );
        shapeFileLoad.addEventListener( 'change', e => {
            const f = shapeFileLoad.files[ 0 ];
            reader.readAsText( f );
            reader.onload = e => { processLoadedShape ( ); } // process data
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Once you set `key`, call `event.preventDefault()`... That said, you may have issues with setting `key` to '' on keyup, if that's how you have that function bound.

Comment: I have now managed it with async await.
Post it as soon as I've worked it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed it.

I had also tried a few things before, but the operating system probably takes control immediately and you have no chance of accessing the field. Hence the idea of delaying the call for a short time, 0.33 to 0.66 seconds proves to be suitable.
The input field then remains empty during normal operation.
A default value cannot be set in this way, but this is not really important in my case.

---

*HTML part and keyboard events as in the question.*

---

```
const delay = sec => { return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout ( resolve, sec * 1000 ) ) }
const openUploadFileWindow = async( ) => { await delay( 0.33 ); shapeFileLoad.click( ) }

shapeFileLoad.addEventListener( 'change', e => {
    const f = shapeFileLoad.files[ 0 ];
    reader.readAsText( f );
    reader.onload = e => { processLoadedShape ( ); } // process data  
} );

function onContainerBpointerDown(event) {
    if (key === 'shape') { openUploadFileWindow( ) }
}
```